# Angularjs directive canvas is blurry

Tags: angularjs, canvas

I created a directive for angularjs which visualizes four distance sensors using **html5's canvas** element.

jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/pgbyvtw7/

Unfortunately **i cannot get the drawing to be crisp and sharp** since everything is kind of blurry (at least on my Nexus5, on my pc monitor it looks okay, but also not nice).

I am basically using

`ctx.arc(x, y, 10, angleBackStart, angleStop, false);`

I am setting the width and height on the canvas element itself not via css. I tried the `ctx.scale(2,2)`thing but it does nothing. I saw some articles shifting things for 0.5 but since the circle is round this doesnt help either.

Somehow it must be possible to get the circles sharp since it is possible for the browser to render stuff like svg and border radius. I read the html5 rocks article about hdpi canvas, but it was too focused on images and fonts, so maybe i missed the thing there.

Is there any way to get the circles sharp?

Answer (score 0):

I updated your fiddle so that it actually scales the cirle with ctx.scale, but it doesn't look that good anyway... Using a scale of 50 removes all antialiasing completely. Using a scale of 0.9 adds a little more antialiasing. Maybe you could try if this shows up any different on you device.

```
var scale = 0.9;
canvas.setAttribute('width', canvas.width * scale);
canvas.setAttribute('height', canvas.height * scale);
ctx.scale(scale, scale);
```

And some CSS to make the canvas the same size as before:

```
canvas {
    width: 175px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pgbyvtw7/1/)

Comment: okay, i see, but this doesnt really solve the problem, i guess the solution is too close to the starting point as the improvements are only small (same on phone and pc). Maybe someone comes up with some background details on this

Comment: No I know, just wanted to share my findings while trying to solve it :)

Comment: BTW try setting the scale to 2. That made the image show up much crispier on my iPad Mini.

Answer (score 0):

First, set your canvas height and width HTML attributes to twice the desired size. So:

```
<canvas height="400px" width="350px">
```

Next, inside your directive's link function, adjust the height and width values to match these HTML attribute values.

```
// The canvas
var height = 400
var width = 350
```

Next, in CSS, set the size of the canvas element to the desired size.

```
canvas {
   width: 175px;
   height: 200px;
}
```

Finally, you'll want to draw your arcs twice as large so that they take up the right amount of space in the CSS-scaled canvas.

The idea here is simple --- we produce a whole rendered canvas at twice the desired size, and then set it to display at half that size with CSS.